# Cells in grid crossed by a line ( PHP )

Tags: php, grid, spatial, mesh

I have a mesh of cells in memory. I know the width and height of the cells, X0,Y0,  X1,Y1,  X2,Y2. Given a line connecting (X1,Y1) to (X2,Y2) I would like a way to determine the cells crossed by this line. I have hashed the cells that should get sellected in my drawing. I would like an idea on how to solve this and i will build the implementation in PHP.

[image: Grid with selected cells]

Comment: It's just the equation of a line and then using your known x and y extents calculate the cells in-between at whatever resolution is sufficient for your needs.

Comment: More recent, but exactly the same with answers: [Find cells in array that are crossed by a given line segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807686)