# line matrix box interception, python

Tags: python, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm using a self made matrix as some kind of map

```
    def __init__(self, rows = 10, colls = 10):
    self.matrixRC = []
    for _ in range(rows):
        self.matrixRC.append([2 for _ in range(colls)])
```

and I was wondering if there was an easy way to make a `y = ax` line function tell me what spaces of my matrix it goes trough (without checking all the points on the line).

An other way to put the problem, how do i know what box of my millimeterpaper my line goes trough (it starts on an intersection of two of my millimeterpaper lines).

p.s. sorry if my explanation isn't to good.

Exmaple:

```
..........
..##....#.
........#.
..........
..........
..........
..........
ss........
ss........
..........
```

so here the place where I start looking is the place in-between the 4 's' and I'd like a function/algorithm which tells me if a line at a certain angle (I'm setting 0 at the top so to the right would be 90 or Pi/2 degrees) hits a square with a `#` and preferably fighter the length of the line at that point of the location of the `#` both are fine.

Comment: You should add a couple examples so that it gets clearer. For example, where do you place (0, 0)? In the left-bottom corner?

Comment: Are you looking for [ray-grid traversal](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/advanced-rendering/introduction-acceleration-structure/grid)?

Comment: Yeah a ray-grid traveral is the thing I thought i was looking for, tough with further consideration i make the decision to use a different way to find the info I needed. Still thx for the help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807686/find-cells-in-array-that-are-crossed-by-a-given-line-segment/35810470#35810470